# Как сделать так, чтобы блок занимал почти всю страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня страница с такой структурой:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="NavPanel">
   </div>
   <div id="container">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

С горизонтальным заполнением все нормально, а вот с вертикальным не очень. Как сделать так, чтобы `div container` заполнял страницу и по высоте, и по ширине?

Comment: `#container {height: 100vh;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```